# Unable to create a VM using azure power powershell

Tags: azure

I am facing some issues while creating VM using Azure PowerShell where i could create and play around directly through portal. Below is the error i am getting. Comments are most welcome to rectify this and Thanks in Advance!

cmdlet New-AzVM at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: test
New-AzVM : Resource 'test' was disallowed by policy. Policy identifiers: '[{"policyAssignment":{"name":"Not allowed
resource types","id":"/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignment
s/XXXXXXXXXX"},"policyDefinition":{"name":"Not allowed resource
types","id":"/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/XXXXXXXX"}}]'.
At line:1 char:1

- New-AzVM
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzVM], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.NewAzureVMCommand
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that there is a policy in your Azure subscription which disallows to create/update VM resources.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/error-policy-requestdisallowedbypolicy

There are two possible options to resolve your problem

- Disable that policy which does not allow VM creation
- Remove VM resource from the policy which disallows to create/update VM resources.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/assign-policy-portal